# "with" statement works in Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, ubuntu, with-statement

I have a script (see below) that runs perfectly in Windows that I'm trying to move to an Ubuntu environment. I have setup the PostgreSQL database exactly the same, with the exact same tables and usernames, etc. However, when I try to run the script in Ubunu it fails when it parses the "with" statement.

Here is the "with" statement:

```
with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)
```

I get the following error:

```
INSERT INTO symbol (ticker, instrument, name, sector, currency, created_date, last_updated_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 502
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loadSPX.py", line 60, in <module>
    insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
  File "loadSPX.py", line 54, in insert_snp500_symbols
    with con: 
AttributeError: __exit__
```

However, if I remove the "with" and change it to the following it works perfectly:

```
cur = con.cursor()   
cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)  
con.commit()
```

Any ideas what is causing this? Here is the full script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import lxml.html
import psycopg2 as mdb
import psycopg2.extras

from math import ceil


def obtain_parse_wiki_snp500():
  """Download and parse the Wikipedia list of S&P500 
  constituents using requests and libxml.

  Returns a list of tuples for to add to database."""

  # Stores the current time, for the created_at record
  now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

  # Use libxml to download the list of S&P500 companies and obtain the symbol table
  page = lxml.html.parse('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
  symbolslist = page.xpath('//table[1]/tr')[1:503]

  # Obtain the symbol information for each row in the S&P500 constituent table
  symbols = []
  for symbol in symbolslist:
    tds = symbol.getchildren()
    sd = {'ticker': tds[0].getchildren()[0].text,
        'name': tds[1].getchildren()[0].text,
        'sector': tds[3].text}
    # Create a tuple (for the DB format) and append to the grand list
    symbols.append( (sd['ticker'], 'stock', sd['name'], 
      sd['sector'], 'USD', now, now) )
  return symbols

def insert_snp500_symbols(symbols):
  """Insert the S&P500 symbols into the database."""

  # Connect to the PostgreSQL instance
  db_host = 'localhost'
  db_user = 'sec_user'
  db_pass = 'XXXXXXX'
  db_name = 'securities_master'
  con = mdb.connect(host=db_host, dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_pass)

  # Create the insert strings
  column_str = "ticker, instrument, name, sector, currency, created_date, last_updated_date"
  insert_str = ("%s, " * 7)[:-2]
  final_str = "INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (column_str, insert_str)
  print final_str, len(symbols)

  # Using the MySQL connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
  with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  symbols = obtain_parse_wiki_snp500()
  insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `psycopg2` library on Ubuntu is too old; you need to upgrade to version 2.5 or newer. In older versions connections do not yet support being used as context managers.

See the [Psycopg 2.5 release announcement](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2013/04/07/psycopg-25-released/):

> #### Connections and cursors as context managers
>
> A recent DBAPI extension has standardized the use of connections and cursors as context managers: it is now possible to use an idiom such as:
>
> ```
> with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
>     with conn.cursor() as curs:
>        curs.execute(SQL)
> ```
>
> with the intuitive behaviour: when the cursor block exits the cursor is closed; when the connection block exits normally the current transaction is committed, if it exits with an exception instead the transaction is rolled back, in either case the connection is ready to be used again

If you installed the [`python-psycopg2` system package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-psycopg2) you are most likely using 2.4.5; only Utopic Unicorn (14.10) has a more recent version (2.5.3). To install the newer version from soure, you'll need to install the Python development headers ([`python-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-dev)) plus the PostgreSQL client library headers ([`libpq-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpq-dev)).

Comment: Wow, had no idea. I keep trying to upgrade via apt-get but it insists I have the newest version, even though it's showing up as 2.4.5. Any idea how I can upgrade this package inside of Ubuntu?

Comment: @JDGD: you could try to install the [Utopic package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-psycopg2); the dependencies haven't changed from Precise Pangolin (12.04) onwards.